# Seek function not working in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

I tried the below code snippet and the seek function doesn't seem to work.

```
funct("ls -ltr /scratch/dummy/dum*");

sub funct {

print "\nRecording\n";
open(SENSOR_LIST1, "$_[0] |") || die "Failed to read sensor list: $!\n";
for $sensor_line1 (<SENSOR_LIST1>) {
   print "$sensor_line1";
}
my $pos = tell SENSOR_LIST1;
print "\nposition is $pos"; #Here the position is 613

print "\nRecording again";
seek (SENSOR_LIST1, SEEK_SET, 0);
$pos = tell SENSOR_LIST1; # Here again the position is 613, even after a seek
print "\nposition now is $pos";

for $sensor_line1 (<SENSOR_LIST1>) {
        print "$sensor_line1";
    }
close SENSOR_LIST1;
}
```

Note: All variants of seek doesn't work.

Output:

The position does not change even after the seek. It remains in 613.

Can you guys, check and let me know what is the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot seek on a pipe.

Either use a temporary file or store the data in memory.

Your choice as to the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the output of your `ls` command to a file and opening that file instead of reading the command's output directly.  You can't `seek` on a transient data stream (such as a command's output), only on data which still exists after being read (such as a file).